# Trying to integrate bbm with a app i am developing

Tags: blackberry-webworks, bb-messenger

I am currently developing a bb app that will require login and i was wondering how can i use bbwork sample sdk to let users with a bbm to login using simply their bbm id. I am not able to find any specific information regarding this. I do know the bbm sdk is avalaible on webworks but i am not sure how i can use the sample provided and integrate it with my app to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the information needed for using BlackBerry Messenger in a WebWorks app right on the Developer Site @ https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.bbm.platform.html